# PartyNotKnownOnLedger (Party not known on ledger)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, daml

I am using DAML-on-Fabric (running DAML based on Hyperledger Fabric).

When I login with `Alice` and issue a IOU, the app shows `PartyNotKnownOnLedger (Party not known on ledger)`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of DAML 0.13.52, the sandbox shipped in the SDK implicitly "allocates" parties for you. This is usually not the case when using actual distributed ledgers (such as Hyperledger Fabric).

To allocate the party, you can either use the SDK assistant `daml ledger allocate-parties` command or apply the `allocateParty` function using DAML script (documentation [here](https://docs.daml.com/0.13.52/daml-script/index.html)).

Alternatively, apps from other languages can use the `AllocateParty` RPC in the `PartyManagementService` in the Ledger API. The Ledger API has available bindings in Java and Scala; there is no available wrapper for the `PartyManagementService` but you can use the raw gRPC-generated code to use them (more on the Ledger API [here](https://docs.daml.com/0.13.52/app-dev/index.html)).

Since the Ledger API is defined with gRPC you can use any other language with gRPC support (more on the topic [here](https://docs.daml.com/0.13.52/app-dev/bindings-x-lang/index.html)).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I resolved this issue by  running 'daml ledger allocate-parties' in the root of quickstart